# How can I add a time stamp to a table row automatically and increment the tote# on change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add the timestamp automatically after the user enters their initials, then the new line will be created and and I will need to increase the tote# of that next line to the next number eg.(on line 2 tote# will be 2)

This is my table structure

```
<table id="harvestedCannabis">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Tote #</th>
                            <th>Flowers</th>
                            <th>Trim A</th>
                            <th>Trim B</th>
                            <th>Waste</th>
                            <th>Originating Line(A,B,C)</th>
                            <th>Preformed By</th>
                            <th>Time Stamp</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td><input type="number" step=".1"></td>
                            <td><input type="number" step=".1"></td>
                            <td><input type="number" step=".1"></td>
                            <td><input type="number" step=".1"></td>
                            <td><input type="text"></td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="preformedBy"></td>
                            <td id="timeStamp"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
```

and here is my JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#preformedBy").change(function(){
        $('#harvestedCannabis > tbody:last-child').append('<tr><td>1</td><td><input type="number" step=".1"></td><td><input type="number" step=".1"></td><td><input type="number" step=".1"></td><td><input type="number" step=".1"></td><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text" id="preformedBy"></td><td id="timeStamp"></td></tr>');
    });
  });
```

I would like the timestamp to be enter automatically and tote# to increase when the user enters their initails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use underscorejs debounce

```
 $('#preformedBy').keyup(_.debounce($('#timeStamp').html(new Date()), 500));
```

for more on debouce with lodash you can read 
https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce

if you dont want to use underscore you can use debounce with jquery read this https://code.google.com/archive/p/jquery-debounce/

and if you just want key up simply you can use

```
    $('#preformedBy').keyup(()=>{
       $('#timeStamp').html(new Date())
    });
```

further you can also spice it up with setTimeout to wait for some user delay to confirm has he finished or not

increment follows same logic just change the targeting html #id

personally i am big fan of lodash one liners are always better to read and debug